Question about existence of path-lifting property
I'm reading "Complex Made Simple" by David C. Ullrich and here i have a problem with the proof of a theorem:
Theorem
Suppose that $p : X \to Y$ is a covering map. If $\gamma : [0,1] \to Y$ is continuous, $x_0 \in X$ and $p(x_0) = \gamma(0)$ then there exists a unique continuous function $\tilde{\gamma} : [0,1] \to X$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = x_0$ and $p \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma$.
This is the proof that author gives: 

To prove the existence, let $A$ be the set of $t_0 \in [0,1]$ such that there exists a continuous $\tilde{\gamma} : [0, t_0] \to X$ with $\tilde{\gamma(0)} = x_0$ and $p(\tilde{\gamma}(t)) = \gamma(t)$ for all $t \in [0, t_0]$. We need to show that $A$ is both open and closed.

I don't know how to show that $A$ is both open and closed, and as a mention I never took a Algebraic Topology class before. I tried to read some books, but can't understand very good what happens there and in the book mentioned by the author (A Basic Course in Algebraic Topology by William S. Massey) I don't find this proof for existence (that one from the book I don't understand). Thanks!

Although this statement is commonly proved in Algebraic Topology textbooks, it's purely a statement on the level of point-set topology and so is its proof. It strikes me as a better idea to try to work through a full proof and ask about what you don't understand concretely.

I don't know exactly how to continue this. In many algebraic topology I've seen something with Lebesgue number and other things that I don't know. I've never seen a proof like this for existence (only for uniqueness was something similar)

There's a proof using nothing but basic point-set topology, albeit to show a more general statement, in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (p. 30). Why are you so attached to this one? Anyway, what have you tried to tackle this problem? As you know this site generally expects you to show some effort of your own.

You asked the same question few days ago. My suggestion is the same: learn the standard proof and do not try to reinvent the wheel.

As mentioned by commentators, the problem is one of point-set topology, so it might be good for you to spend some time to study the subject (as it is used in algebraic topology, in complex geometry, in differential equations, etc.). The intuition behind the proof here is quite simple, despite what the length of the following formal answer might suggest.
We want to prove existence of a lift to $\gamma$ starting at $x_0$, i.e., existence of a continuous path $\tilde{\gamma} : [0,1] \to X$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = x_0$ and  $p \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma$. Following Ullrich's lead, let $A \subset [0,1]$ be the set of $t_0 \in [0,1]$ such that there exists a continuous path $\tilde{\gamma} : [0,t_0] \to X$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = x_0$ and  $p \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma|_{[0, t_0]}$. Proving existence of a lift thus amounts to proving that $A = [0,1]$; since $[0,1]$ is a connected space, it suffices to prove that $A$ is a non-empty, open and closed subset of $[0,1]$.
Nonempty: $0 \in A$ since we can take $\tilde{\gamma} : \{0\} = [0,0] \to X$ given by $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = x_0$ and $p(\tilde{\gamma}(0)) = p(x_0) = \gamma(0)$.
Open: Consider $t_0 \in A$. By definition, there exists a continuous path $\tilde{\gamma} : [0,t_0] \to X$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = x_0$ and  $p \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma|_{[0, t_0]}$. Define $x_{t_0} := \tilde{\gamma}(t_0)$ and $y_{t_0} = \gamma(t_0)$, so that $p(x_{t_0}) = y_{t_0}$. Since $p : X \to Y$ is a covering space, there are neighborhoods $U$ of $x_{t_0}$ in $X$ and $V$ of $y_{t_0}$ in $Y$ such that $p|_U : U \to V$ is a homeomorphism. By continuity of $\gamma$, there is a open interval $I$ around $t_0$ in $[0,1]$ such that $\gamma(I) \subset V$; we thus get a well-defined map $\tilde{\tilde{\gamma}} = (p|_U)^{-1} \circ \gamma|_I : I \to U$. Of course, $\tilde{\tilde{\gamma}}(t_0) = x_0 = \tilde{\gamma}(t_0)$ and over $J := [0,t_0] \cap I$, we have $p \circ \tilde{\tilde{\gamma}}|_J = \gamma|_J = p \circ \tilde{\gamma}|_J$. By the gluing lemma for continuous functions, it follows that we have a well-defined continuous path $\hat{\gamma} : [0,t_0] \cup I \to X$ defined by
$$ \hat{\gamma}(t) := \begin{cases} \tilde{\gamma}(t) & \mbox{ if $t \in [0,t_0]$,} \\ \tilde{\tilde{\gamma}}(t) & \mbox{ if $t \in I$.} \end{cases} $$
By construction, we have $\hat{\gamma}(0) = x_0$ and $p \circ \hat{\gamma} = \gamma|_{[0, t_0] \cup I}$. Hence, since $\hat{\gamma}$ exists, we deduce that $t \in A$ for all $t \in I$, i.e., $I \subset A$. That is, $A$ contains an open neighborhood of any of its point, i.e. $A$ is open.
Closed: Let $t_0 \in \bar{A}$ (the closure of $A$). Again, set $y_{t_0} := \gamma(t_0)$. Consider a small enough open neighborhood $V$ of $y_{t_0}$ in $Y$ such that $p^{-1}(V)$ is a disjoint union of open sets $U_{k}$ ($k \in K$ some index set) such that $p|_{U_k} : U_k \to V$ is a homeomorphism for every $k \in K$. By continuity of $\gamma$, there is an open interval $I$ around $t_0$ in $[0,1]$ such that $\gamma(I) \subset V$. Since $t_0 \in \bar{A}$, there exists a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ in $A$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = t_0$; since $I$ is an open interval around $t_0$ in $[0,1]$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $t_n \in I$. In particular $t_N \in A \cap I$, so there exists a a continuous path $\tilde{\gamma} : [0,t_N] \to X$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = x_0$ and  $p \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma|_{[0, t_N]}$. Define $x_{t_N} := \tilde{\gamma}(t_N)$ and define $U$ to be the unique $U_k$ containing $x_{t_N}$. Similarly as in the Open case, consider the unique lift $\tilde{\tilde{\gamma}} := (p|_U)^{-1} \circ \gamma|_I : I \to U$. Over $I \cap [0, t_N]$, $\tilde{\tilde{\gamma}}$ and $\tilde{\gamma}$ coincide, so by the gluing lemma, we can define a continuous path $\hat{\gamma} : [0,t_N] \cup I \to X$ by
$$ \hat{\gamma}(t) := \begin{cases} \tilde{\gamma}(t) & \mbox{ if $t \in [0,t_N]$,} \\ \tilde{\tilde{\gamma}}(t) & \mbox{ if $t \in I$.} \end{cases} $$
Once again, this $\hat{\gamma}$ satisfies $\hat{\gamma}(0) = x_0$ and $p \circ \hat{\gamma} = \gamma|_{[0, t_N] \cup I}$. It follows that $I \subset A$, but $t_0 \in I$, so $t_0 \in A$. Since $t_0$ was arbitrary in $\bar{A}$, this proves $\bar{A} \subset A$, i.e. $A$ is closed.
Remark. Note that in the Closed case, we used the local uniqueness of lifts (which is a direct consequence of the fact that $p$ is a local homeomorphism).

Thank you very much!!! Now I understand!
